# list_columns() multiple table?

Tags: php, sql, fuelphp

title says, is there a way to select column name from multiple table?

```
DB::list_columns('table1'); //returns columns of table1
```

what I want to do is

```
DB::list_columns('table1', 'table2');
```

I want to select all columns of 2 or more tables.
is it possible?

Comment: Nope, doesn’t look like it from a quick glance at the docs. But since all this does is return an array, it should be no big problem to call it twice, and then combine the results into one array in necessary.

Comment: `list_columns($table, $like = null, $db = null)` -> **table** and _not tables_

Answer (score 0):

Use `DB::list_tables()` in foreach read the current table using `DB::list_columns($current_table)`

If you use PDO_Connection, this is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who replied, here is what I did

```
$col1 = DB::list_columns('table1');

foreach ($col1 as $key => $value) {
    array_push($columns['col1'], $key);
}

$col2 = DB::list_columns('table2');

foreach ($col2 as $key => $value) {
    array_push($columns['col2'], $key);
}

$colnames = array_merge($col1, $col2);
```

@CBroe thanks for giving me idea!